# Для чего нужен знак % в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
p = (p + 1) % n;
```

При этом `n = 6.`

Comment: Это оператор остатка: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder

Answer (score 6):

Оператор `%` означает - "остаток от деления на". Этот код, выполняемый в цикле, будет крутить значение `p` от нуля до пяти.

```js
var p = 123;
var n = 6;
for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  p = (p + 1) % n;
  console.log(p);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`%` - оператор остатка. Если после операции деления остался остаток он будет возвращен оператором, иначе он вернет 0.

Пример с https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder:

```
12 % 5 // 2
-1 % 2 // -1
1 % -2 // 1
NaN % 2 // NaN
1 % 2 // 1
2 % 3 // 2
-4 % 2 // -0
5.5 % 2 // 1.5
```